# How to harmonize a color image

Tags: image-processing, opencv

i'm searching a approach to harmonize the colors of some images.

<s>On youtube i found a video which illustrate it:
http://youtu.be/DvrUYtLju4Y But they doesn't add some paper or a implementation.</s>

Have someone an idea?

**//Update**

Okay, sry. Of course i read a paper befor i asked this question. See [Color Harmonization](http://www.igl.ethz.ch/projects/color-harmonization/harmonization.pdf). 
There i read about something about some hue-"harmonize pattern". They generate a hue-histogram from the current image and compare it with these templates. My problem is to find the best template for the current image. A normal compare of 2 histograms doesn't work, because there is an angle.

**The question is how can i find the best pattern for my image?**
[image: harmonize pattern]

greetings

Comment: I don't understand why the downvotes. I believe this is a valid and possibly useful question.

Comment: Frm what I see in the video, the templates/patterns are just predefined color palettes a user can select to apply to a picture. They are not automatically selected/created

Comment: jeah...but i want to find it automatically

Comment: What do you mean by asking "how can i find the best pattern for my image?"?

Comment: i want to find out which pattern/template ( which displays of the image obove) have the best hitrate to the hue-histogram of my image. The problem is, that every template (cycle) can rotate up to 360 degree. Shure, i could shift the color of the hue-histogram up to 1...359 degree. But this is very slow, isn't it? :D
greetings

Comment: It's no best "pattern there". It's just about preferences - you tell the app to use some greenish colors because you love green, and the algorithm does its best to find the most suitable green palette for your image. Selecting the palette is a 100% personal choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There is no built-in solution in OpenCV**. But there are publications on this subject.

Check: 
[Color Harmonization for Augmented Reality](http://www.icg.tu-graz.ac.at/Members/denis/publication/colorharmonizationforaugmentedreality/)

Answer (score 3):

After 5 seconds of googling I found [article about Color harmonization](http://www.igl.ethz.ch/projects/color-harmonization/harmonization.pdf) which uses images from video.

And here's [another paper](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~niloy/research/vid_harmonize/paper_docs/vidHarmonize_icvgip_08.pdf).

Comment: `there are some color arrangements specially those motivated by coexisting colors in nature, which are universally considered to be harmonious` I think the premise of those papers (that the beauty of color arrangements can be computed) is seriously flawed.

Comment: @Simon anyway the first article contains images from the video so it seems to be a exactly that article which destiny is looking for (read the question).